# is there a way to uv unwrap both sides of face into different parts?

Tags: modeling, uv

hi im new to blender and i want to know if i can paint in different color both side of this faces without using any shader, i tried uv unwraping but always when i paint one side of the face the other is painted too this is the object im trying to paint. [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't unwrap differently for a simple material, but you can use a *Geometry* shader node to select different colors for each side of the face.  Here's a very simple example:

[image: Backfacing material]

On an open cylinder this will make the inside of the cylinder orange and the outside blue:

[image: Simple cylinder]

Now you can use the same UV Map but drive Color1, the outside, with an image texture that you painted.  You can then either use a simple color for Color2, the inside, or the same UV map with a different image, or, I suppose a different UV Map with a different image texture.  The material for the last case would look like this:

[image: Complicated material using two UV Maps]

Comment: thank you so much for answering it i had a lot of problems trying to figure it out